# SSRS Conditional Text Color Based On Other Group's Value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

To simplify my need: I am comparing a projected sales number to the budgeted sales number and need to color the Projected amounts as red, black, or green, based on whether they are less, equal, or greater than the corresponding Plan amounts.  Essentially my data boils down to

```
║ Group ║ Amount ║   Type    ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║     1 ║ .95    ║ Projected ║
║     2 ║ 0      ║ Projected ║
║     3 ║ .04    ║ Projected ║
║     1 ║ 1.3    ║ Plan      ║
║     2 ║ 0      ║ Plan      ║
║     3 ║ .03    ║ Plan      ║
```

My tablix is using a column grouping based on the `Type`.

I tried the following Expression, but it's giving me Green when it should be Red.
`=iif(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)<SUM(iif(Fields!Type.Value = "Plan",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"Type"),"Red",iif(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)>SUM(iif(Fields!Type.Value = "Plan",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"Type"),"Green","Black"))`

My desired output is the following:

[image]

Comment: Are you using a matrix? or do you have two different fields for Projection Amount and Plan Amount?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta A matrix.  But now that I think about it, it might just be easier to rewrite the stored procedure to make it into 2 different fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be easier if you change your query to retrieve the data in a different way. However I'll expose a SSRS and a T-SQL solution:

**SSRS Solution:**

Add a calculated field to your dataset and concatenate the `Group` and `Type`.

```
=Fields!GroupID.Value & "-" & Fields!AmountType.Value
```

I am using the data you put in your question in order to recreate your scenario. Supposing you are using a matrix to get the desired output just use this data arrangement:

[image]

Now in Amount cell font color property use the following expression:

```
=IIF(
Fields!AmountType.Value="Projected",
  IIF(
     Fields!Amount.Value >
     Lookup(Fields!Group.Value & "-" & "Plan",Fields!GroupType.Value,Fields!Amount.Value,"DataSet3"),
     "Green",
       IIF(
           Fields!Amount.Value <
           Lookup(Fields!Group.Value & "-" & "Plan",Fields!GroupType.Value,Fields!Amount.Value,"DataSet3"),
           "Red","Black"
          )
     ),"Black"
)
```

You have to change `Fields!GroupType.Value` according to the name you set for the calculated field.

It will preview the following matrix:

[image]

> This solution will only work if you compare only two different types:
>   `Projected` and `Plan`

**T-SQL Solution (recommended):**

Change your dataset query to get the data in a proper way to compare it. Based on the table you posted I've used this query.

```
SELECT
  a.GroupID,
  a.Amount [Projected],
  pl.Amount [Plan]
FROM your_table a
INNER JOIN (SELECT
  *
FROM your_table
WHERE AmountType = 'Plan') pl
  ON a.GroupID = pl.GroupID
WHERE a.AmountType = 'Projected'
```

It produces:

[image]

Try yourself by this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/6731/0):

With the T-SQL solution the comparation between plan amount and projected amount is trivial in SSRS.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: I went with the re-writing of my query, but thank you for explaining both methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are comparing the total of **Projected + Plan** with **Projected** so it would always be greater.

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Projected", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)) < SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Plan",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"Type"), "Red", 
 IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = "Projected", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)) > SUM(iif(Fields!Type.Value = "Plan",Fields!Amount.Value,0),"Type"), "Green", "Black"))
```

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, and I was thinking about trying something like that.  But I think you're missing that under my current tablix setup, the Column grouping is filtering the Projected from Plan.  So when I say `iif(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)<` it should only be summing Projected or Plan, based on which Column grouping is shown.  I think you're solution will work if I remove the Column grouping, but then I'll need to modify my `SUM` formula, which just might have to be what I have to do.

Comment: Ah - I missed the Grouping. Now that I think about it more, it's because you aren't filtering your dataset SUM with your **GROUP** (1, 2, 3). You can either change your fields to filter by PLAN or Projected or use a LOOKUP SUM to get the answer with `LookupSet(Fields!Group.Value & "|" & "Projected", Fields!Group.Value & "|" & Fields!Type.Value, Fields!Amount.value, "Type")` and summing the total.